# Fit an equation into the template

Tags: equations, border

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{SCITEPRESS}
\subfigtopskip=0pt
\subfigcapskip=0pt
\subfigbottomskip=0pt
\hyphenpenalty=2000
\exhyphenpenalty=2000

\begin{document}
          \begin{gather}
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}\label{5}
            A_1P_3&=\omega(3-i)[\lambda(2^{\omega(1.5-ratio)})\vee\lambda(2^{\theta(14-z)})]\vee\omega[\lambda(2^{\omega(1.5-ratio)})],\\
            A_1P_4&=\omega(4-i)[\lambda(2^{\omega(1.2-ratio)})\vee\lambda(2^{\theta(10-z)})],\\
     \end{aligned}
      \right.
      \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Considering above formula, I want to know that how it is possible to fit the equation into the template's border in a way that line 1 does not exceed the border line.

The template that I am using can be found at [here](http://www.kdir.ic3k.org/GuidelinesTemplates.aspx) at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Into which template? Using the standard `article` class, for example, the equation doesn't protrude into the right margin.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina please look at the update. However, it uses the article but with a specific package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option (I left the preamble as in the template even though it loads obsolete packages):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{SCITEPRESS}     % Please add other packages that you may need BEFORE the SCITEPRESS.sty package.

\subfigtopskip=0pt
\subfigcapskip=0pt
\subfigbottomskip=0pt

\begin{document}

\title{Authors' Instructions  \subtitle{Prepa\textup{ratio}n of Camera-Ready Contributions to SCITEPRESS Proceedings} }

\author{\authorname{First Author Name\sup{1}, Second Author Name\sup{1} and Third Author Name\sup{2}}
\affiliation{\sup{1}Institute of Problem Solving, XYZ University, My Street, MyTown, MyCountry}
\affiliation{\sup{2}Department of Computing, Main University, MySecondTown, MyCountry}
\email{\{f\_author, s\_author\}@ips.xyz.edu, t\_author@dc.mu.edu}
}

\keywords{The paper must have at least one keyword. The text must be set to 9-point font size and without the use of bold or italic font style. For more than one keyword, please use a comma as a separator. Keywords must be titlecased.}

\abstract{The abstract should summarize the contents of the paper and should contain at least 70 and at most 200 words. The text must be set to 9-point font size.}

\onecolumn \maketitle \normalsize \vfill


\begin{gather}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}\label{5}
A_1P_3 
&=\omega(3-i)[\lambda(2^{\omega(1.5-\textup{ratio})})\vee\lambda(2^{\theta(14-z)})] \\ 
&\qquad{}\vee\omega[\lambda(2^{\omega(1.5-\textup{ratio})})],\\
A_1P_4
&=\omega(4-i)[\lambda(2^{\omega(1.2-\textup{ratio})})\vee\lambda(2^{\theta(10-z)})],\\
\end{aligned}
\right.\raisetag{2\baselineskip}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I broke the first line into two parts and used `\raisetag` to correct the tag position.

Comment: in `\raisetag{2\baselineskip}`, what is `2` standing for?

Comment: @lonesome `2\baselineskip` means two times the `\baselineskip` length.

Comment: so it takes the tag into second line and if 3, then to the third line?

Comment: @lonesome Without it, the tag gets wrongly placed below the equation, so `\raisetag` corrects its position.

Comment: @lonesome I chose `2\baselineskip` to raise it by multiples of `\baselineskip` (the vertical separation between two consecutive lines), buy you could use another value, for instance `\raisetag{20pt}`, the idea is to find the proper length so that the tag gets properly positioned.

Comment: Understood. There are two more related questions. Hope you do not mind. First, consider a situation that there are a lot of long equations that makes it ugly or hard to read if we break the line for all of them (which is not yet my case). Is there any way to give two columns to equations, like the way that it is done for `figure`?  and second, is there any preference to remove the italic from words by using `\textup` or it is just your way?

Comment: @lonesome For the case you describe, you can wrap the equation in a `figure*` environment. That will make it span both columns but eill move it to the top of the next page. `\textup` is the "canonical" way to typeset text in math expressions to guarantee it appears in upright (Roman) font.